# How to obtain only non-array values from json root properties

Tags: javascript, json

How can I programmatically get only the key/value of non-array values from the root of a JSON object in Javascript?

```
// sample input
{
    name: "Jackie",
    age: 26,
    friends: [ "David", "Ashley" ],
    pets: [ "Rover" ],
    birthday: "May 3",
    family: [
        {
            name: "Lily",
            relationship: "Mother"
        },
        {
            name: "Richard",
            relationship: "Father"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
// expected output
{
    name: "Jackie",
    age: 26,
    birthday: "May 3"
}
```

Comment: Loop over the properties. If the type of the property is an object, delete the property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `Object.entries()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`.

```js
const data = {
    name: "Jackie",
    age: 26,
    friends: [ "David", "Ashley" ],
    pets: [ "Rover" ],
    birthday: "May 3",
    family: [
        {
            name: "Lily",
            relationship: "Mother"
        },
        {
            name: "Richard",
            relationship: "Father"
        }
    ]
};

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => (typeof val !== 'object' ? {...acc, [key]: val} : acc), {});

console.log(res);
```

#### Update

The multiline version of the same code would be

```
const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, val]) => {
  if (typeof val !== 'object') {
    acc[key] = val;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
```

Comment: `typeof val !== 'object'` will exclude objects as well as arrays. `!Array.isArray(val)` is a more correct test.

Comment: Array is a ```typeof``` object and ```instanceof``` Array. So it's appropriate. And what if any value of the ```data``` object is an ```object``` instead of ```Array```?

Comment: OP wants all "non-array values". Your test excludes array objects as well as non-array objects. It excludes more values than requested.

Comment: An answer not only for OP but the others who will visit this later too.

Comment: So why not fix your answer to avoid confusion?

Comment: What is the confusion part? JavaScript measures Array and Object both as object type. So there is no confusion.

Comment: The confusion is that you have answered a question that wasn't asked. Q: how do you exclude arrays? Your answer: This method excludes all objects.

Comment: Which is not asked?

Answer (score 3):

What you think on that :

```js
 Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter( ([k,v]) => Object(v) !== v ))
```

This expiration will filter out every key with object value. of course, you can custom this filter for your needs

```js
 Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter( ([k,v]) => !Array.isArray(v) ))
```

---

Or maybe like @bramer suggest but is modify the original obj

```js
for ( let k in obj )
  if ( Array.isArray(obj[k]) delete obj[k]
```

Can be wrapped to return new obj

```js
function justPrimitive( obj, ret = {} ) 
 for ( let k in obj )
   if ( ! Array.isArray(obj[k]) ret[k] = obj[k]
 return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray):

```js
const data = { name: "Jackie",  age: 26,  friends: [ "David", "Ashley" ],       pets: [ "Rover" ], birthday: "May 3", family: [{name: "Lily", relationship: "Mother" }, { name: "Richard", relationship: "Father" }]};

const result = Object.entries(data)
                     .filter(([k, v], i) => !Array.isArray(v))
                     .reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
                          a[k] = v;
                          return a;
                     }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple readable solution using Array.isArray() rather than checking if the type is an `object`(which causes problems as nested objects are omitted).

```js
const input = {
  name: 'Jackie',
  age: 26,
  friends: ['David', 'Ashley'],
  pets: ['Rover'],
  birthday: 'May 3',
  family: [{
      name: 'Lily',
      relationship: 'Mother',
    },
    {
      name: 'Richard',
      relationship: 'Father',
    },
  ],
};

const results = {};

for ([key, value] of Object.entries(input)) {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    results[key] = value;
  }
}

console.log('results', results);
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple method:

```
    let out = {};
    Object.entries(inp).forEach(ent => {
      const [key, value] = ent;
      if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
        out[key] = value;
      }
    });
    console.log({ out });
    // { out: { name: 'Jackie', age: 26, birthday: 'May 3' } }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = {
    name: "Jackie",
    age: 26,
    friends: ["David", "Ashley"],
    pets: ["Rover"],
    birthday: "May 3",
    family: [
        {
            name: "Lily",
            relationship: "Mother"
        },
        {
            name: "Richard",
            relationship: "Father"
        }
    ]
}

Object.filter = (obj, predicate) =>
    Object.keys(obj)
        .filter(key => predicate(obj[key]))
        .reduce((res, key) => (res[key] = obj[key], res), {});

var filtered = Object.filter(json, item => {
    return typeof item !== 'object' ? true : false
});

console.log(filtered);
```